# Continue session to next view in gamekit

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

I'm using gamekit for bluetooth file transfer. It is working perfectly in first view. Once the connection is established I want to continue the same session in next view. How to do this?

EDIT:
I have taken GKSession object in AppDelegate so that I can use this throughout my application, but I am unable to get that session for more than 1 class in which delegate picker. I want to use app.currentSession in next page so that data exchange can continue in next class as well.
Code:

```
   -(IBAction) Connect:(id)sender{

    picker = [[GKPeerPickerController alloc]init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.connectionTypesMask = GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeNearby;

    [btnConnect setHidden:YES];
    [btnDisconnect setHidden:NO];
    [picker show];
    }

   - (void)peerPickerController:(GKPeerPickerController *)picker1 didConnectPeer:(NSString *)peerID toSession:(GKSession *) session{
    app.currentSession = session;
    session.delegate = self;
    [session setDataReceiveHandler:self withContext:nil];
    picker.delegate = nil;

    [picker dismiss];
    [picker autorelease];
    }
```

Comment: @Nick.I think this code is enough to understand.

Comment: @GajendraKChauhan As per my other comment to you - this question has been edited since I answered it to include the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your code, there could be many many reasons for this.  However, I assume that you are creating your GKSession in some method in your view.  I would suggest that this is not the correct place and you need to revisit your application design.

Comment: I think She posted enough info.

Comment: @GajendraKChauhan There is more info now, but if you look at the history of the question you will see that originally there was not much information.